# Is there a way to recover registry entries that were deleted using RegDeleteKey?

Tags: registry, recovery, disaster-recovery

[I am aware that this might actually better belong on superuser but I thought the programmer perspective might yield slightly better/faster results.]

I have just written a sleek new configuration framework for our apps and everything was working just great. There was only one function left to test and that was deleting a registry key (recursively). As everything else had been working exactly as expected I became inexcusably careless and made what was very probably a fatal mistake: I ran the test not step-by-step in the debugger but live...

Seems I made a mistake in the path handling and now **everything** below `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software` that wasn't locked or otherwise inaccessible at the time of the test is gone.

I used Delphi 2009's `TRegistry.DeleteKey` method which in turn recursively calls the `RegDeleteKey` API. Is there some way to undo this either programmatically or using utilities (preferably freeware)?

I am actually rather surprised the system is still running (I am writing this from that machine). I have not logged of or rebooted since this happened. I guess the entries are all cached in memory by the running applications. Can they maybe be brought back from there as well?

System Restore reports that no restore points have been created on this machine though I'm sure there were. Could this also be a symptom of the purged registry? Can this be overcome somehow?

This is on Windows 7 Enterprise (32bit).

HALP!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least it was HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

If roaming profiles are enabled, grab it from the profile store.

If not, it's lost.

Answer (score 0):

A decade later now: Yes, there exists freeware to experimental search for deleted registry keys/values just before. Though its not spread as public information and general google results will not lead to the downloads, forensics already use them with success.
[I work as an IT specialist and in my spare time did some research for registry accidents beforehand, thats the reason for why I can answer this.]

Two programs are:

1. `Yaru` (shareware, still heavy bugs, compatible with Windows XP)
2. `RegistryExplorer` (freeware, no XP-Support, needs NET 4.0 / NET 6.0, no bugs found so far)
   https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/EricZimmermanTools/net6/RegistryExplorer.zip
   (NET 6) or
   https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/EricZimmermanTools/RegistryExplorer.zip (NET 4)

I have tried both and urgently recommend using RegistryExplorer since it is free, have a much better GUI and does not mix up dwords/binarys like yaru does.

**Important**: You have to run RegistryExplorer.exe with elevated rights - without it will start too but Registry hives can not be loaded!!! And keep in mind: Those programs can only retrieve registry keys/values that had exist for a while before got deleted (or had seen at least one reboot). Such that are created and then deleted immediately within one session the program will NOT able to find/restore!